# @react-navigation/stack could not be found

Tags: react-native

@react-navigation/stack could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
../node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Comment: Which react-navigation version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of react-navigation you are using, cause the imports for version 4x is different from 5x. Check in your package.json which version of react-navigation you installed and use the appropriate import.